# IBM SBT SDK: How can I fetch Community description as HTML?

Tags: ibm-sbt

When I have a `Community` object, I can use `setContent()` to enter HTML text to be displayed as part of the Community Overview page.

On the other hand, when I have fetched an existing Community object e. g. as member of `community.getSubCommunities()` and call `subcommunity.getContent()`, I receive `null`. If I call `subcommunity.getSummary()`, I only receive the plain text (cleaned, no HTML).

How can I fetch the existing HTML content?

(Rationale: I have built some nice "content template" as HTML and want to use this for other communities programmatically. In the IC UI I cannot display the HTML source code afaik, I can only see the "rich text".)

**Versions:**

IBM SBT SDK 1.0.2.20140527-1807 deployed on Tomcat 7.0.53 running on Java 7, firing against IC v4.5 using BasicAuth.

**EDIT 20140725:**
I corrected the text "call `subcommunity.getContent()`, I receive `null`". I had NULL in lt/gt pair which did not render here at all. Sorry :-(

Comment: I could not understand your question. By API definition, Content is html and Summary is the plain text version of the description. So getContent() should return the HTML content. Both return the same value with plain text?

Comment: try it: I did not find any HTML in what getContent() returns after having used setContent(someHtml).

Comment: I actually had a look into the XML returned from "my" IC45 instance. And the interesting thing is: The "content" node is empty. Nothing inside. Only the "summary" node is filled, but obviously with plain text.

Comment: Meanwhile the system is upgraded to IC5, but XML response is unchanged with respect to "content" and "summary": "summary" is filled with plain text, and "content" is empty (but present). -- The request types are "fetch my communities" and "fetch sub communities of XYZ". Maybe this is a reason for "content" being empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to fetch the community by CommunityService.getCommunity(communityUuid) instead of taking a CommunityList entry from the result of CommunityService.getMyCommunities() or the like.

As it seems the only (or at least main) difference between a CommunityList entry and an explicitly fetched Community entity is that in the list entry set the content field is always e

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are pulling a `Community` object, just after setting `Content`, trying to get `Summary` but you don't get the plain text version of the HTML content.

This is simply because of that the plain text version of the description is not being computed within the `Community` class. It's a wrapping class for the atom entry that represents a community. Therefore you have to submit the community back to the server by saving it, so you can receive the modified plain text value.

Comment: Please see my text correction of the question :-/ --- getContent() returns NULL, and getSummary() returns plain text. But getContent() should return HTML source.